# Anonymous WCF service not callable using Channel Factory

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, proxy

I am migrating a service reference to use a channel factory.

I split the interface from the service implementation into a separate class library.

- Class Lib: `IService`
- Class Lib: `Service`
- Web Application: Reference to `IService`

Code:

**Config**

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingEndpoint" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**Class:**

```
public class ProxyManager
{
    internal static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChannelFactory<IService>> proxies = 
                    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChannelFactory<IService>>();

    internal static ChannelFactory<IService> CreateChannelFactory()
    {
        Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:CreateChannelFactory");
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://domain/Service.svc");
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
        return channelFactory;
    }

    internal static IService GetProxy(string key)
    {
         Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:GetProxy");
         return proxies.GetOrAdd(key, m => CreateChannelFactory()).CreateChannel();
    }

    internal static bool RemoveProxy(string key)
    {
        Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:RemoveProxy");
        ChannelFactory<IService> proxy;
        return proxies.TryRemove(key, out proxy);
    }
}
```

**Global:**

```
public static IService ServiceProxy
{
    get
    {
        return ProxyManager.GetProxy("Service");
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ServiceProxy.Method();
```

**Error:**

Exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at `http://domain/Service.svc` that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> InnerException:The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

1. The service is reachable on `"http://domain/Service.svc"`
2. The service has "Anonymous" Authentication enabled and "Windows" Authentication disabled on IIS

What am I missing here?

**Troubleshooting:**
1. I tried setting the binding to have "BasicHttpSecurityMode.None" which did not help.
2. Tried setting the Channel Factory windows credentials to "TokenImpersonationLevel.Anonymous" which did not help
3. Tried reading the IsAnonymous property of the endpointaddress and it is false

Is it possible to set the channel or channel factory to be anonymous?
Is it possible to set the channel or channel factory to have a namespace?

**Detailed error messages:**

```
Exception:
Message: There was no endpoint listening at http://domain/Service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Source: mscorlib
StackTrace: Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService.Method()
TargetSite: Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
HelpLink:
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

InnerException:
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Source: System
StackTrace:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
TargetSite: System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()
HelpLink: 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
```

Comment: Have you tried going to `http://domain/Service.svc` in a browser?  How are you hosting the service, and is it running when you try to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Service had two endpoints - Ajax and Basic.

I had not mentioned that I wanted to use the Basic endpoint in the ProxyManager.

Once I changed the code segment below it worked:

```
internal static ChannelFactory<IService> CreateChannelFactory()
    {
        Global.Logger.Info("ProxyManager:CreateChannelFactory");
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://domain/Service.svc/Basic");
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
        return channelFactory;
    }
```

The error message was not clear to me because the service address worked. I should have corrected the endpoint address based on the error message.